# how to pass localstorage from popup.js to content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, message-passing

i want to pass data from localstorage of popup.hmtl to content script content.js
i use popup.html to receive username and password and store it in local storage.Now i want to transfer the data to content script before it execute.

```
**popup.html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
Username:
<td><input id="u1" type="text" name="uname">
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Password:
<td><input id="u2" type="password" name="pass">
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<td>
<input id="clickme" type="button" value="save" />
</tr>

</table>

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick=myfunction;
var sname = localStorage.getItem("username1");
var spass=localStorage.getItem("password1");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("username1");
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("password1");

function myfunction(){

// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {

    var uname="bhuwan";
    var username=document.getElementById("u1").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("u2").value;

    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("username1", username);
    localStorage.setItem("password1",password);
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("username1");
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("password1");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getLocalStorage")
      sendResponse({data: localStorage[request.key]});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

**content.js**

```
{
var pid="";
var cid="";


chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getLocalStorage",key="username"}, function(response) {
  var cid = response.data;

});
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getLocalStorage"},key="password" function(response) {
  var pid = response.data;

});


}
```

**I Found the answer:**

Transferred the following code to background .js from popup.js

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.method == "getLocalStorage")
          sendResponse({data: localStorage[request.key]});
        else
          sendResponse({}); // snub them.
    });
```

since popup.js is active only when the icon is clicked.So No Message Passing was possible.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as an edit to the question. Keep to the SO format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve data by messaging the popup page.

The problem with this: popup page only exists as long as it's shown. When it's closed, it is destroyed, your `onMessage` listener does not exist, and the request fails.

This is precisely what [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) are for - persistent event listeners. Furthermore, a background page shares `localStorage` with the popup, so no problems there.

---

All that said, there is a better alternative to `localStorage` that's available both to popup and content scripts without any messaging: [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: Transfered the code to background.js ,itworked like charm...thanks

Comment: `This is precisely what background or event pages are for - persistent event listeners` -  If only we could give more than 1 upvote at a time. Thank you.